# Absolute positioning without extending parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to position a "seeker" in a div element that has other elements in it. I want the seeker to be able to move on top of the content div, without pushing other content around, while also following the scrollbar. The area is resizable so I can't use constant width/height. Like the seeker in a video editor would.

This is what I've gotten so far

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: gray;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 120px;
}

#box {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
}

#seekerContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#seeker {
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
      <div id="seekerContainer">
        <div id="seeker"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I've tried different combinations having the seekerContainer and seeker be position absolute/relative, but either the seeker wont follow the scrolling, or it extends the height of the div.

Any pointers to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.content {
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
}

.seeker {
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  left: 10%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="seeker"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, you don't want to put `id` on every element and use `id` for styling. You should use `classes` for that. ID of the element has to be unique for the page so it's not very useful when you need to apply the same styling to more elements.